# Delete of Service gives error

Tags: ibm-cloud

When trying to delete an service it gives errors. The "Microservices-OrdersAPI-marcvl-1526" has a route to an ElephantSQL. The error I get is:

```
{ "code": 10001, "description": "Service instance myMicroservicesSQL: Service broker error: {\"description\"=>\"Error 500 received from broker url https://bluemix-eu-gb.marketplace.ibmcloud.com/api/custom/cloudfoundry/v2/service_instances/ffa09d28-1774-46b5-ac36-8e8cc87d098c/service_bindings/57f38a3e-a522-4de2-9f09-179a6c770088?plan_id=4dfed884-0a35-4a76-ab61-e122117f3efe&service_id=45c4b1ce-ae64-11e3-8e2c-00259086a7bc\"}", "error_code": "CF-ServiceBrokerBadResponse", "http": { "uri": "https://provision-broker.eu-gb.bluemix.net/bmx/provisioning/brokers/29240c6e-d36b-4b4f-8628-4c5de43d6c61/v2/service_instances/ffa09d28-1774-46b5-ac36-8e8cc87d098c/service_bindings/57f38a3e-a522-4de2-9f09-179a6c770088", "method": "DELETE", "status": 500 } }
```

Please advice how to delete these two. Deleting others did work.

Comment: No code involved. It's done interactively with the Bluemix GUI.

Comment: Just reissued a delete with the current (see timestamp) GUI. Now it works. Everything is deleted.